# Expectation of time integral of Wiener process

Tags: stochastic-calculus, pr.probability

I am trying to calculate $E(\int_0^T {W_s ds})$, where $W_s$ is a standard Brownian motion.

Now two approaches I can think of:

1) Take a partition of $[0,T]$. Calculate $E(\sum {W_{t_i}(t_{i+1} - t_i)})$ and take the limit as you shrink the size of the partition.

2) Calculate $\int_0^T { E(W_s)ds }$.

However, for approach 1), its not clear what function would dominate the absolute value of the terms inside the E() for all possible partitions, and that it would have a finite expectation. So, interchanging limit and expectation is dicey.

For approach 2), Fubini's theorem would require me to know a-priori that $E(\int_0^T {|W_s|ds})$ is finite, and I don't see how I could show that.

How can any of these approaches be fixed, if at all? Or is there another way to solve the problem?

Comment: Brownian motion is a martingale (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_%28probability_theory%29); the expectation you want is always zero. Also voting to close as this would be better suited to another site mentioned in the FAQ.

Comment: If BM is a martingale, why should its time integral have zero mean ?
(Although, yes, both approaches will give me an answer of 0).

Also, the problems with the approaches I mentioned are valid for questions like calculating E(\Int_0_T {W_s^2 ds})

Comment: If I have the distribution of Max{|W_s|:0<s<T}, I could try showing that its expectation if finite. This would let me validate both the approaches.
If someone has a reference where this is calculated, please let me know.

Comment: Martingales are in $L^1$.

Comment: Does not seem to be MO level question.

Comment: More appropriate for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Martingales are in L1
-------------
So Fubini Thm goes through. Ok, many thanks.

Comment: @Cosmonut: The distribution of the running maximum is computed in  section 2.8A of Karatzas and Shreve's *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus*.  Though as my answer mentions, you don't really need it here.

Comment: I think it's related to the expectation of the time integral of wiener process. I'm curious to use the first approach to find its variance. I'm the beginner in stochastic calculus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For approach 2, Fubini's theorem works just as well if you show
$$ \int_0^T E|W_s|ds  < \infty $$
which is easy.  Indeed, perhaps even easier is to note
$$ \int_0^T E(|W_s|^2)ds = \int_0^T s ds = \frac{1}{2}T^2 < \infty$$
and use Jensen/Hölder/Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: This is the way to do it.  Any invocation of martingales, running maximum, etc., is overkill for this problem.  

Comment: Thanks, I like this. Looks like this approach can be generalized to work out the expectation of integrals of various functions of a Weiner process as well, such as exp(W_s).

Answer (score 8):

It is possible to integrate by parts in $\int_0^T B(t) dt$ and obtain

$-B(t) (T-t)|_{t=0}^{t=T} + \int_0^T (T-t) dB(t) \overset{d}{=} \int_0^T (T-t) dB(t)$

The Wiener integral on the right has a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\int_0^T (T-t)^2 dt = T^3/3$.

Edit:  Sorry, I used $B$ instead of $W$ to denote Brownian motion.

Comment: This is really cool! 

I had worked out the variance of \Int_0_T {W_s ds} the hard way by partitioning [0, T] into n parts, calculating the variance of the sum and then letting n go to infinity. I got the correct answer, (thanks for verifying that :)) but was once again worried about limit interchange issues.

Although, I'm guessing there must be some technical isses involved in justifying the integration by parts formula and equating the time integral to a stochastic integral.
(I guess you are implicitly using Ito's lemma ?)


Comment: Slightly technical, but not bad:  If h is a function with bounded variation on [a,b] and g is continuous on [a,b], then the Riemann-stieltjes integral \int_a^b g(x) dh(x) can be defined by approximating with step functions.  Then, applying integration by parts, you can define the integral \int h(x) dg(x) as h(x)g(x)|_a^b - \int g(x) dh(x).  

Since W is almost surely continuous, and (T-t) has bounded variation, you apply this fact omega by omega to g(t) = W(t,\omega). See pages 12 and 13 in Kuo's book Introduction to Stochastic Integration for more detail.

Comment: This is the canonical answer according to: http://math.nyu.edu/faculty/goodman/teaching/StochCalc2004/notes/l6.pdf

Comment: Unclear why you're able to conclude that the Wiener integral on the right is normally distributed with these properties